# Why are statically positioned children of a fixed position element gaining width?

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7, css-position

*UPDATE:*

This seem to only be an issue with `ul`/`li` if i replace the `ul` with a `div` and remove the `li` and apply the relevant style to the `a`'s instead its fine. ID' still liek to know why the `ul`/`li` structure presents a problem since margin/padding have been reset explicitly.

---

Im having soem trouble with the children of a fixed position element in IE7. They seem to be gaining width/margin/padding from somewhere but I cant discern where or how to fix it.

You can take a look at it in [jsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/Y8rHb/). Ive added the bg colors just for debugging. The image/li tags should be flush with they yellow, and are in IE8 as well as mozilla and webkit. But in IE7 there is an extra ~20px of space to the left pushing them over, as if the `li`, `a`, or `img` tags had a margin. However, if i look through the properties in IEDevToolbar there is no margin or padding being applied. Futhermore, this happens even if i assign widths to everything and zero out margin/padding directly on each element with IEDevToolbar.

I'm totally lost on this one.

Below is the relevent code... There is a XHTML 1.0 Transitional doctype on the layout in question:

```
<style type="text/css">
 .social-widgets {
    position: fixed;
    top: 125px;
    left: 0px;
    background: #f00;
    width: 34px;
  }
  .social-widgets-content {
    list-style: none inside none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: left;
    background: #ff0;
  }
  .social-widgets-content li {
    margin: 10px 0 !important;
    padding:0; 
    width: 34px;
    background: #0f0;
  }
  .social-widgets-content img {
    display:block;
    border-top: 2px solid #e9e8e8;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #e9e8e8;
    border-right: 2px solid #e9e8e8;
    padding: 0px; margin:0px;
    background: #00f;
  }
</style>

<div class="social-widgets">
  <ul class="social-widgets-content">
    <li><a href="#"><img src="/images/button/button.facebook.png"></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><img src="/images/button/button.twitter.png"></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><img src="/images/button/button.feedback.png"></a></li>
  </ul>
</div> <!-- /.social-widgets -->
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has nothing to do with `position:fixed;`. It was an issue with the list styling. When using `list-style: none inside none;` IE7 still adds the spacing for the list-marker despite the marker being set to `none`. The solution was to set `list-style-type: none;` instead of using the shorthand.